# R is giving error : there are aliased coefficients in the model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lm

After running this code:

```
lin_reg3 <-lm(MonthlyIncome~.+I(Age^2),data=szurtdataset)
summary(lin_reg3)
resettest(lin_reg3,vcov=vcovHC, type = "regressor")
```

I get this error:

```
> resettest(lin_reg3,vcov=vcovHC, type = "regressor")
Error in waldtest.lm(lm(y ~ 0 + X + Z), "Z", vcov = vcov, ...) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

Is there an easy way to get around this? If the part `+I(Age^2)` is not included, it works just fine.